# Powershell: how escape many special chars as data, not operators?

Tags: string, powershell, char, escaping, quoting

Got a problem understanding how to escape out chars in PS, so they are *not* interpreted as operators or instructions. I'm writing a PS script to find chars in filenames which are to be forbidden, and replace those chars for other chars (or remove).
This includes typing the unwanted chars into the code:

```
$UnsupportedChars = '[!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®¯]'
```

The first apostrophe (') above, indicates the start of the variable's content, and the apostrophe at the end of the variable indicates the end of the variable's content. Problem is that I also need to include the apostrophe inside the variable's contents as a 'not allowed char in filenames'. (see 7th char in var contents above)

This causes PS to interpret the (second) apostrophe as the end of the variable contents, as opposed to the third apostrophe which is standard. Surprisingly, using the grave-accent to escape doesn't work, PS won't accept it as valid code.

Same thing later in the code, in the loop which goes through-, finds- and exchange chars. I will need to include the quotation char (") as a 'not allowed chars in filename'. This presents the same kind of problem, which PS will not allow as valid code:

```
if ($_.Value -match """) { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace """, "") }
```

Again, using the grave-accent to escape doesn't work, PS won't accept it as valid code:

```
if ($_.Value -match "`"") { $newFileName = ($newFileName -replace """, "") }
```

Problem seems to be how to declare all those special chars (see variable above) and separate them as data, as opposed to operators.
Is there a way to encode this in PS, or will it be necessary to write a specific function to address this?

Comment: If I understand your *objective*, I think you might find a "*negated* whitelist" character class would be more concise: `'$m"y&fi>le@3.t#x/t\' -replace '[^A-Za-z0-9\.]'` == yields => `myfile3.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

The **escaping requirements** in **PowerShell [string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules)** are:

- In ***verbatim***, *single*-quoted strings, [**`'...'`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings):

  - By design, all characters are used *verbatim* in such strings - no string interpolation is applied.
  - Purely for *syntactic* reasons, however, **`'` itself must be escaped, as `''`** - but see the next section about *here-strings*.
- In ***expandable***, i.e. interpolating, *double*-quoted strings, [**`"..."`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings):

  - The **following characters** need escaping in order to be used *verbatim*:

    - `"`, for *syntactic* reasons - but see the next section about *here-strings*.
    - `$`, to avoid string interpolation (e.g. `"$HOME"`, `"$(1 + 2)"`)
    - `` ` ``, to avoid interpretation as part of an [escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) (e.g. `` "`t" `` to produce a tab char.)
  - They **must be escaped with `` ` ``**, the **so-called *backtick***, which is PowerShell's *escape character*; **`"` may *alternatively* be escaped as `""`**

Examples:

```bash
# -> 6' tall
'6'' tall'

# -> 3" of snow
"3`" of snow" # or: "3"" of snow"

# -> You owe me $5.
"You owe me `$5."

# -> `t produces [  ]
"``t produces [`t]"

# -> '
''''

# -> "
"`"" # or: """"
```

---

Note that PowerShell string literals are also available in a ***multiline* variant form** called [***here-strings***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings), which offer two **benefits**:

- Conceptually clearer definition of *multiline* strings.
- No need to escape embedded *quote* characters (but in the *double*-quoted (expandable) form, you still need to escape `$` and `` ` ``, as needed).

Examples:

```bash
# No need to escape ' (or ")
# -> 6' tall.
@'
6' tall.
'@

# No need to escape " (or '), but - if needed - $ and ` still do.
# -> 3" of snow. `t expands to [    ]
@"
3" of snow. ``t expands to [`t]
"@
```

---

As [Keith Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9406738/keith-miller) notes, a conceptually clear way of **composing a string from a *mix* of verbatim and interpolated parts or expression results** is to use **`-f`**, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), which allows you to use a *verbatim* string as a *template* into which values are spliced based on *placeholders* such as `{0}`.

Examples:

```bash
# Same as: "``t produces [`t]"
# Avoids the need to escape ` in the template.
# {0} is a placeholder for the first RHS operand.
'`t produces [{0}]' -f "`t"

# Same as: "2 to the power of 5 is $([Math]::Pow(2, 5))"
# Avoids the need for $(...) enclosure.
'2 to the power of 5 is {0}' -f [Math]::Pow(2, 5)
```

Comment: Glad to see you added info on here-strings. Saw this yesterday and was coming back to add a supplemental answer to that effect. I think the [`-f` (Format operator)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f) deserves mention as well. Useful for things like inserting tabs and newlines in literal strings: `'hello{0}{1}world' -f "\`n","\`t"` and sometimes a more readable alternative to a complex expansion string with subexpressions...

Comment: Thanks, @KeithMiller - I've added a new bottom section to cover `-f` use.